# Azure Application Insight: Stream Telemetry to a file

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm interested in gathering some metrics on who and when someone is assigned/removed from a task.  The idea is to use that data for machine learning purposes.

Since I feel that storing those metrics in SQL Server would be pointless due to its read-only nature of and the potential volume of rows that would be created, I wanted to use Azure's Application Insights to record those metrics.

While logging those events should be straightforward, I would also like to know whether it's possible to stream those events to a file so that my machine learning model can process them?  That way, if data is purged from Application Insights, I would have a backup.

Alternatively, what ways can I have my machine learning model get data from Application Insights?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options:

1. Query data and store it in a format you like
2. Export data (using Diagnostics Settings) to Event Hub/Azure Storage [service side]
3. Implement your [TelemetrySink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.extensibility.telemetrysink?view=azure-dotnet) (the link is for .NET, should be available for other languages as well) which will save exactly the same events wherever you want in a format you need.